# int() argument must be a string when trying to do a form in django

Tags: python, django, forms, web, integer

i have a problem. I am trying to do a edit form with django. But when i go to the url to edit for example: /adminview/edit/1/

i got the message:

```
TypeError at /adminview/edit/1/
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 
'builtin_function_or_method'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/adminview/edit/1/
Django Version: 2.1.5
Exception Type: TypeError
```

this is my urls.py:

```
app_name = 'adminview'

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', index_admin, name="adminview"),
url(r'^clasification', clasification, name="clasification"),
url(r'^edit/(?P<id_category>\d+)/$', edit_clasificacion, name="edit_clasificacion"),
]
```

and this is a part from my views.py where i have the function that i am trying to built:

```
 def edit_clasificacion(request, id_category):
   clasificacion = Clasificacion.objects.get(id=id)
   if request.method == 'GET':
       form = ClasificacionForm(instance=clasificacion)
   else:
       form = ClasificacionForm(request.POST, instance=clasificacion)
       if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
       return redirect('article:index')
   return render(request, 'adminview/clasification.html', {'form':form})
```

this is my forms.py:

class ClasificacionForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
    model = Clasificacion

    fields = [
        'nombre_clasificacion',
        ]
    labels = {
        'nombre_clasificacion': 'Nombre de categoría',
    }
    widgets = {
        'nombre_clasificacion': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'})
    }
```

any help? thanks a lot!

Comment: What does the stack trace say from the console?

Comment: Can you include the form?

Comment: Did you mean `Clasificacion.objects.get(id=id_category)`? `id` is a built-in function, and you don't appear to have shadowed it.

Comment: @markwalker_ i have include the forms.py so you can see it...

Comment: @andreihondrari it doesnt say nothing, the console says that it works correctly.

Comment: @chepner if i use that i get a new error  "Clasificacion matching query does not exist", because the primary ID from my database is called just "id"...

Comment: @chepner if i use that i get a new error  "Clasificacion matching query does not exist", because the primary ID from my database is called just "id"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you are using `Clasificacion.objects.get(id=id)`, but `id` is never defined (and is a reserved keyword/function).

To fix your code, use the `id_category` parameter you defined in your view's signature:

```
def edit_clasificacion(request, id_category):
    clasificacion = Clasificacion.objects.get(id=id_category)
    ....
```

Comment: I have tried that but it gets a new error, "Clasificacion matching query does not exist", because the primary ID from my database is called just "id"... :/.

Comment: @LuisBermúdez All it means is that there is no `Clasificacion` object in your DB with the ID of `1` (since that is the ID you used in your URL). Try the url with an ID that you know exists, and it should work.

Comment: No problem! One addition - it is better to use `clasificacion = get_object_or_404(Clasificacion, id=id_category)`, since it will give a proper error message and http 404 status if the wrong ID is in the url. You can read more about it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404